# Is it possible to persist/serialize/deserialize a JS Generator? (in node.js, or any other engine)

Tags: javascript, node.js, serialization, deserialization, generator

Let's assume I run one JS file with the following code:

```
function* naturalsGenerator(){
  let num = 0;
  while(true){
    yield num++;
  }
}
const naturals = naturalsGenerator();
console.log(naturals.next().value); // prints 0
writeInAFile(naturals,"file.bin");
```

And then I run the following script:

```
const deserializedGenerator = readFromFile("file.bin");
console.log(deserializedGenerator.next().value); //prints 1
```

Is there any way to implement `writeInFile` and `readFromFile` functions, in node.js or any other js engine?

Comment: Not without a server side script. Javascript doesn't have access to the filesystem for security reasons. The only way to circumvent that would be to write a form and use a FileReader to read it out. When done, generate a filestream that's pushed towards the browser as a download. It'll require the user to both select the file in the form and save it manually

Comment: No, generators can't be serialized. They're dependent on the dynamic state of the JS environment, and there's no way to save that.

Comment: Wouldn't the first example result in `file.bin` being infinite in size?

Comment: For `readFromFile` function does it just convert every byte into a int between -127 and 127?

Comment: @Barmar Look at the edit history please. It didn't at the time of me commenting :)

Comment: @programmerRaj Only if it tries to write the values returned by the generator. The OP is asking if there's a way to write the generator itself to the file.

Comment: @Barmar Oh ok. Except in the example `writeInAFile(naturals,"file.bin");`, `naturals` is an iterator, not a generator. So this is even more complicated as the state of yielding `0` already also needs to be stored in the file.

Comment: @programmerRaj Right. That's why this is not possible in general. Imagine a generator that reads from a stream. How would the file save the state of the stream, which could be connected to a file, network, etc.?

Comment: @programmerRaj you're right, it's not the generator I want to persist. But the iterator created by the generator.